# TypeScript 0.9.1 CommonJS: correctly declaring exported ambient class implementing external interface?

Tags: class, interface, typescript, commonjs, ambient

EDIT:

Put another way the following within a **.d.ts** file shouldn't produce compiler error TS2137 'Class "MyClass" does not implement interface "IInterface"':

```
interface IInterface {
    someMethod():void;
}
declare module "mod" {
    export class MyClass implements IInterface {
        constructor();
    }
}
```

because I'm not (and can't in a declaration) implementing anything. Is this a bug in the compiler or is there some other way/syntax to do what the above implies? I would think the compiler smart enough to know to precisely include IInterface's signature as part of MyClass, and not require its methods be redeclared.

ORIGINAL:

I'm trying to write a d.ts for the node component bunyan. Having a problem with exporting a class that implements an external interface, specifically RingBuffer which extends node's EventEmitter. The problem simplified is (below in a bunyan.d.ts file):

```
// this interface declared in <reference..., put inline here for simplicity
interface IExternal {
    inheritedMethod():void;
}

interface RingBuffer extends IExternal {
    write():void;
}
declare var RingBuffer: {
    new():RingBuffer;
}

declare module "bunyan" {
    export var RingBuffer;
}
```

then used in myNodeApp.js

```
/// <references path="bunyan.d.ts" />

import bunyan = require( 'bunyan' );
var rb = new bunyan.RingBuffer();

// compiler doesn't error on this; thinks RingBuffer is type any.
// also, no intellisense to show write() method.
rb.badFunc();
```

---

changing bunyan.d.ts to:

```
declare module "bunyan" {
    export class RingBuffer { constructor(); }
}
```

compiles, but same problem when used; no intellisense, no compile errors.

---

changing bunyan.d.ts to

```
declare module "bunyan" {
    export var RingBuffer:RingBuffer;
}
```

causes compile error in myNodeApp.js

```
// error TS2083: Invalid 'new' expression
import rb = new bunyan.RingBuffer();
```

---

removing from bunyan.d.ts

```
declare module "bunyan" {
    ...
}
```

causes compile error in myNodeApp.js

```
// error TS2071: Unable to resolve external module ''bunyan''
import bunyan = require( 'bunyan' );
```

---

changing bunyan.d.ts

```
interface IExternal {
    inheritedMethod():void;
}
interface IRingBuffer extends IExternal {
}

declare module "bunyan" {
    export class RingBuffer implements IRingBuffer {}
}
```

cause compile error

```
// error TS2137: Class "bunyan".RingBuffer declares interface IRingBuffer but 
// does not implement it: type '"bunyan".RingBuffer' is missing property
// 'inheritedMethod' from type 'IRingBuffer'
```

implying I have to redeclare all inherited methods from all extended interfaces, besides IRingBuffer, which seems a bit ridiculuous to have to do in a d.ts file

Does anyone know the 'correct' way to declare an ambient class that implements an interface for consumption in another CommonJS module??

Comment: thanks basarat. What exactly is the compiler bug? I hope its that declaring a class to also implement an interface, in a d.ts file, that I don't have to essentially to re-declare the interface in the class declaration. If in the declaration I say 'class MyClass implements IInterface', its interface signature for IInterface should be implied, and not have to be typed all over again...

Comment: after further investigation, I was wrong. Updated answer with solution :)

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14587529/1176284) explains why inherited member declaration is obligatory in ambient declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate way to define it would be the way Jquery's typescript definition is defined. You have separate interfaces for static and instance members. Here is a sample complete definition:

```
interface IExternal {
    inheritedMethod():void;
}

interface IRingBuffer extends IExternal {
    write():void;
}
// Static functions and constructors 
interface IRingBufferStatic{
    new():IRingBuffer;  
}
declare var RingBuffer:IRingBufferStatic;

declare module "bunyan" {
    export var RingBuffer:IRingBufferStatic;
}

// In the second file 

import bunyan = require( 'bunyan' );
var rb = new bunyan.RingBuffer();

// you get an error here 
rb.badFunc();
```

[Try it online](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20IExternal%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20inheritedMethod%28%29%3avoid;%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IRingBuffer%20extends%20IExternal%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20write%28%29%3avoid;%0A%7D%0A//%20Static%20functions%20and%20constructors%20%0Ainterface%20IRingBufferStatic%7B%0A%20%20%20%20new%28%29%3aIRingBuffer;%09%0A%7D%0Adeclare%20var%20RingBuffer%3aIRingBufferStatic;%0A%0Adeclare%20module%20%22bunyan%22%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20var%20RingBuffer%3aIRingBufferStatic;%0A%7D%0A%0A//%20In%20the%20second%20file%20%0A%0Aimport%20bunyan%20=%20require%28%20%27bunyan%27%20%29;%0Avar%20rb%20=%20new%20bunyan.RingBuffer%28%29;%0A%0A//%20you%20get%20an%20error%20here%20%0Arb.badFunc%28%29;)

Comment: Thats it! Thanks basarat, much appreciated.