# Typescript Definition file: Duplicate interface members to implementing classes?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.6, definitelytyped

I am trying to write a compact typescript definition file, but I am having troubles doing so for a larger project.

My project has lots of interfaces that are implemented by a number of classes.

From what I can see I always need to re"implement"/redeclare the methods of the interfaces in the classes like so:

```
declare module someModule {

    interface InterfaceOne {
        /**
        * Some lengthy description
        */
        someStuff():any;
        /**
        * Some lengthy description
        */
        moreStuff():any;
    }

    class OneClass implements InterfaceOne {
        /**
        * Some lengthy description
        */
        someStuff():any;
        /**
        * Some lengthy description
        */
        moreStuff():any;
        /**
        * Even more description
        */
        classStuff(): any;
    }

    class TwoClass implements InterfaceOne {
        /**
        * Some lengthy description
        */
        someStuff():any;
        /**
        * Some lengthy description
        */
        moreStuff():any;
        /**
        * Even more description
        */
        classStuff(): any;
    }
}
```

If I leave out the `someStuff` and `moreStuff` declarations from the interfaces 
I get this error:

> error TS2137: Class TwoClass declares interface InterfaceOne but does not implement it:

So I always need to copy all of the declarations to each and every class that implements the interface.

Is there some way around that? Why do I need to do that? Is there any good reason for having to copy the combined contents of all interfaces to the class bodies in a library declaration file? It's a declaration only, not the implementation, so why isn't my declaration `implements InterfaceOne` enough already? I don't need to copy all base type members from a super type to an extending type, either, so why is this different for interfaces?

In the library that I am writing the definition file for these interfaces are actually mixins so in the end my definition file actually gets longer than the original implementation that has the bodies!

*Edit:* After posting I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14587529/351836) - so my question is likely to be a duplicate, although the other question is for a far older version of Typescript.

*Edit:* I realize this may not be the correct place to discuss this and I am thinking about deleting this question. For reference, I asked the question in [this official typescript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5468).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried interface/class merging?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

```
export interface Foo {
    bar: string;
}

export class Foo {
    constructor() { this.bar = 'foobar'; }
}

export interface AnotherFoo extends Foo {}

export class AnotherFoo {
    foo = 'bar'; // add a foo member only to this class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

```
declare module someModule {

    interface InterfaceOne {
        /**
         * Some lengthy description
         */
        someStuff():any;
        /**
         * Some lengthy description
         */
        moreStuff():any;
    }

   interface OneClass extends InterfaceOne {
       new(): OneClass;
       /**
         * Even more description
         */
        classStuff(): any;
   }

   interface TwoClass extends InterfaceOne {
       new(): TwoClass;
       /**
         * Even more description
         */
        classStuff(): any;
   }

}
```

(did this in a bus, needs more checking)

Comment: Thanks, but another more crucial problem is this means `OneClass` and `TwoClass` can not extend from another (possibly different) class anymore. And that's what interfaces are for - to be implemented by different/unrelated classes. My library is pure Javascript and even without the duplication the .d.ts file is 8MB in size, so even if created automatically it would still be huge.

Comment: OK. There is a "pure" interface solution to describe this using a Factory for the constructor and variables. It is bit convoluted but when I have a few minutes I will try to edit the answer

Comment: Completely edited my answer. Yup... Class Interfaces. Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407036/how-does-typescript-interfaces-with-construct-signatures-work

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, unfortunately this is the situation that I *have* already (the 8 MBs) and that I am trying to get away from. Because if I model everything with interfaces, this is works, but having no classes means no one can extend my classes anymore properly. I want to model my library as precisely as possible to get the most out of typescript. No classes means no subclassing :-(

Comment: OK never mind but for the sake of the argument: you do not *have* this situation: there is no duplication is my example and I do not get your argument about subclassing: this is just a definition file,  and you can always extend an interface (modeling a class)

Comment: Mmmh - here is what I want to be able to do ultimately: Can you get this to work with your ideas? Define an interface, let a class implement that interface and have the client (the consumer of the d.ts file) be able to extend that class and override one of the interface members and call super()? I may be blind or incapable but I just can't get this to compile.